# Why does IResource.getRawLocation() return null for IProject

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I need the absolute location of a project folder, so I tried

```
project.getRawLocation()
```

but this returns `null` (at least in my case in which I have imported the project manually using *Import ... Existing projects into workspace* and I have checked the *Copy projects into workspace* checkbox).

The thing is that

```
project.getParent().getRawLocation()
```

returns `/work/Projekte/runtime-MyProduct.product` which is correct

and

```
project.members()[0].getRawLocation()
```

returns `/work/Projekte/runtime-MyProduct.product/Test/.cproject` which is correct as well.

Consequently, I'd expect that

```
project.getRawLocation()
```

would return `/work/Projekte/runtime-MyProduct.product/Test`, but it returns `null`.

Can anyone explain and/or show me where I'm wrong?

Comment: Can you check the ResourceInfo of the project. may be its 'phantom'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The JavaDoc for [`getRawLocation()`](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fcore%2Fresources%2FIResource.html&anchor=getRawLocation()) says

> If this resource is an existing project, the returned path will be
>   equal to the location path in the project description.

and the JavaDoc for the project description [`IProjectDescription.getLocation()`](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fcore%2Fresources%2FIProjectDescription.html&anchor=getLocation()) says:

> null is returned if the default location should be used

The [`getLocation()`](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fcore%2Fresources%2FIResource.html&anchor=getLocation()) call will return a path.

Comment: My project is an existing project, but still getRawLocation() returns null .. probably this is because my project has no "location path" set in the project description". Actually the name of this eclipse-method is real bad. It should be named getProjectDescriptionPath(). However getLocation() works fine for my project. I would consider that as a bug in eclipse.

Comment: @Alex Read the Javadoc carefully - getRawLocation says it returns the path from the project description (the IProjectDescription.getLocation) call. IProjectDescription.getLocation says that it will return null if the default location is being used - so null is expected for an ordinary project.

Comment: The doc does not matter for my argument. It's just about expectations.  If I call a method, called "getRawLocation()" of an existing project I would expect to get the raw location. Anything else is bad design / bad method naming. A good documentation is no excuse for wrong method naming.