# What is the difference between getLocation() and getRawLocation() methods?

Tags: java, eclipse

getRawLocation() method returns null if i import the project from workspace
and it returns correct path location if i import the project from any other location. but getLocation() method returns path in both the cases.

Comment: So you've answerred by yourself, what's the difference. Now what is your question?

Comment: I believe it is for the same reason as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20493654/why-does-iresource-getrawlocation-return-null-for-iproject

Comment: @Tagir Valeev,my question is why getRawLocation() method returns null just because of changing the location location of project??

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fcore%2Fresources%2FIResource.html).

> getRawLocation() : Returns the file system location of this resource,
>   or null if no path can be determined.

Thus you don't have path that can be determined and hence got null.

[Here](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fwidgets%2FControl.html)

> getLocation(): Returns a point describing the receiver's location
>   relative to its parent (or its display if its parent is null), unless
>   the receiver is a shell.